# How to concatenate 3 lists in Prolog without using append

Tags: prolog

I know how to concatenate 2 lists without append but how would you go about concatenating 3 lists without append.

Comment: How do **You** concatenate 2 lists without append (or a similarly defined predicate/non-terminal)?

Comment: Maybe you just concatenate two lists several times in a row? But impossible to tell with the way you have asked your question. It needs more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could [foldl](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/swipl_notes/about_foldl/README.md) your catenate function over a list of lists.

```rust
list_list_catenate([E],   L, [E|L]).    %// [4]   cat [a,b,c] is [4,a,b,c]
list_list_catenate([H|T], L, Cat) :-    %// [4,5] cat [a,b,c] is [4|(5 cat [a,b,c])]
    list_list_catenate(T, L, TCat),
    Cat = [H|TCat].


Lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
reverse(Lists, RevLists),
foldl(list_list_catenate, RevLists, [], Result).
```

Fold left is a loop structure common in functional programming languages, it pushes each of the list items into the helper, along with the result of the previous time, so they aggregate up.

And this needs a `reverse` because of the way foldl maps the arguments to the helper; without that, it goes `[1,2,3], []` then `[4,5,6], [1,2,3]` then `[7,8,9], [4,5,6,1,2,3]`.